# Fetch info in bootstrap card

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-4, web-deployment, bootstrap-cards

I am trying to display cards but in this way, all three cards are showing the same information whereas I want every card to show specific entries in the database like 1st one the first entry and second one the second then the third one the third then change line and restart to display 4,5,6 entry and so on. Can anyone please help?

```
include_once('db/connection.php');
        $query="select * from news ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    
           ?>
    <?php
    
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {  
        $cc =$rows['category2'];
        ?>
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="cust_bloglistintro">
                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 cust_blogteaser" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin-bottom: 32px;height: 750px;">
                            <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 700px;"><img class="card-img-top w-100  d-block" src="images/<?php echo $rows['thumbnail'];?>">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></h4><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $rows['3']; ?></span>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo substr($rows['2'],0,400); ?></p><?php if($cc=="bigbites"){?><a class="card-link" href="bigbites.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php } else{?><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo $rows['7']; ?>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php }?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center" style="bottom: 10px;"><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" id="whatsapp"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" id="facebook"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" id="linkedin"></i><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fas fa-share" id="share"></i></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 cust_blogteaser" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin-bottom: 32px;height: 750px;">
                            <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 700px;"><img class="card-img-top w-100  d-block" src="images/<?php echo $rows['thumbnail'];?>">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></h4><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $rows['3']; ?></span>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo substr($rows['2'],0,400); ?></p><?php if($cc=="bigbites"){?><a class="card-link" href="bigbites.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php } else{?><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo $rows['7']; ?>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php }?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center" style="bottom: 10px;"><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" id="whatsapp"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" id="facebook"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" id="linkedin"></i><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fas fa-share" id="share"></i></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 cust_blogteaser" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin-bottom: 32px;height: 750px;">
                            <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 700px;"><img class="card-img-top w-100  d-block" src="images/<?php echo $rows['5'];?>">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['1']; ?></h4><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $rows['3']; ?></span>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo substr($rows['2'],0,400); ?></p><?php if($cc=="bigbites"){?><a class="card-link" href="bigbites.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php } else{?><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo $rows['7']; ?>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php }?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center" style="bottom: 10px;"><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" id="whatsapp"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" id="facebook"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" id="linkedin"></i><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fas fa-share" id="share"></i></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You probably want to use a loop - what does `$rows` array look like, please show (a sample of) `var_export($rows);`

Comment: @berend there is already a loop and $rows is a regular associative array

Comment: @jibsteroos sorry?

Comment: then you just shouldn't duplicate cards, displaying only **one** per database row

Comment: @YourCommonSense if I will not duplicate the cards then it just changes rows and I want to display 3 columns per row.

Answer (score -1):

Many ways of doing this, but I've used this approach recently...

```
<?php
    
    $resultCount=0;
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
    {
?>
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="cust_bloglistintro">
                    
                        <div class="row">
<?php
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {  
            $cc =$rows['category2'];
            ?>

                         <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 cust_blogteaser" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin-bottom: 32px;height: 750px;">
                            <div class="card" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 700px;"><img class="card-img-top w-100  d-block" src="images/<?php echo $rows['thumbnail'];?>">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></h4><span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $rows['3']; ?></span>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo substr($rows['2'],0,400); ?></p><?php if($cc=="bigbites"){?><a class="card-link" href="bigbites.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php } else{?><a class="card-link" href="<?php echo $rows['7']; ?>" target="_top">Read more...</a><?php }?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center" style="bottom: 10px;"><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" id="whatsapp"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" id="facebook"></i></a><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" id="linkedin"></i><a href="extra.php?ii=<?php echo $rows['0']?>"><i class="fas fa-share" id="share"></i></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
<?php
            $resultCount++;
            if ($resultCount % 3 == 0) // start new row
            {
?>
                        </div>
                
                    
                        <div class="row">
<?php
            }
        }
        
        if ($resultCount % 3 != 0) // if we didn't just end a row in the loop, end it now
        {
?>
                        </div>
<?php
        }

        // now close divs
?>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    } // end of if num_rows>0
?>
```

Comment: this code is noting new, it's the same as in the question

Comment: @YourCommonSense Really?? How so?

Comment: my bad it's different but you don't need no such tricks with bootstrap

Comment: @YourCommonSense Agreed, you can flow a card at a time in each loop iteration and handle row splits in BS. A minus 1 is pretty harsh for a working PHP solution though as it is literally what the OP asked for. Looking forward to your full BS4 solution.

Comment: this is not working. It displays the next card in the next row instead of the next column.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tried to search it on google but non of them worked specifically for my needs that's why I posted it here.

Comment: I didn't tell the OP to use Google. I told *you* to use Google if you want a BS4 solution you asked from me.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapSingh edited answer to add a missing </div> in the html inside the loop. Hopefully fixes.